# How can I find all of the emails listed in this file and delete everything else?

Tags: json, email

I have a file filled with objects in JSON format containing an email property for thousands of users.

```
{  
   "object":"list",
   "read_only":{  

   },
   "full_access":{  
      "data":[  
         {  
            "id":"32923939",
            "platform_id":"12313",
            "name":"test",
            "email":"test@example.com",
            "created_date":"08 Feb 17 10:02 +0000"
         },
         {  
            "id":"135541",
            "platform_id":"1234",
            "name":"test",
            "email":"test@example.com",
            "created_date":"08 Feb 17 10:00 +0000"
         },
         {  
            "id":"484949383",
            "platform_id":"494948",
            "name":"test",
            "email":"test@example.com",
            "created_date":"08 Feb 17 08:46 +0000"
         },
         {  
            "id":"595033",
            "platform_id":"test",
            "name":"test",
            "email":"test@example.com",
            "created_date":"30 Sep 16 17:51 +0000"
         }
      ]
   },
   "never_logged_in":{  

   }
}
```

The problem I am facing is that some of the objects are not formatted correctly, so I am unable to work with them in code. I am wondering if there is a way that I can search the file for a string, "email:", followed by the email address, and delete everything else. I feel like I can accomplish this using regex, to detect the email address, but I am unsure of how to do it myself.

Could anyone offer any insight or recommendations?

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: json is not a programming language, it's just a format with which to encode data. What is the language you're using?

Comment: I use JavaScript, but I can't because most of the file is formatted incorrectly. I was given a file with a bunch of responses from an API that somehow got manipulated so I am trying to filter out things that arent emails without having to code anything.

Comment: you can start with JsonData.full_access.data.map(obj=>obj.email?obj.email:"bad format")

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, you can do something like -

```
var myJson = {"object":"list","read_only":{},"full_access":{"data":[{"id":"32923939","platform_id":"12313","name":"test","email":"test@example.com","created_date":"08 Feb 17 10:02 +0000"},{"id":"135541","platform_id":"1234","name":"test","email":"test@example.com","created_date":"08 Feb 17 10:00 +0000"},{"id":"484949383","platform_id":"494948","name":"test","email":"test@example.com","created_date":"08 Feb 17 08:46 +0000"},{"id":"595033","platform_id":"test","name":"test","email":"test@example.com","created_date":"30 Sep 16 17:51 +0000"}]},"never_logged_in":{}}
var result = myJson.full_access.data.filter(x=>x.email && x.email!="")
                                    .map(x=>x.email);
console.log(result);
```

It will check if an element in the `data` property has `email` (`.filter` method), and then map out the email ids in an array.

Here's a [JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/91retox1/). Check the console for output.

Note : If you just want to do it as a one time activity, paste the original object you received in the Fiddle and just copy the `result` object from console.
Also, you can use a linter like [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/) to check where all the JSON is breaking.

Comment: Great answer, but most of the file is formatted incorrectly, so I'm trying to just read through the file and recognize anything with an email address and save it.

Comment: That would be a very hectic and manual process. You can use a linter for validating and pointing out errors in the JSON. I believe that correcting the JSON and then using the above method would be faster than manually copying each email. https://jsonlint.com/